# which is fast query for Laravel, Eloquent, Simple query or Raw query

Tags: laravel, performance

In Laravel applications we can write queries by different methods i.e., e.g., Eloquent, Simple Query and Raw Query, I want to learn which type of method is fast for data base operations

Answer (score 2):

All of these eventually use the same way of querying and the speed difference is negligible.

But if you really want to know, I would suppose Eloquent is the slowest, closely followed by the query builder. and a raw query will be the fastest as there is no query building to be done.

My advice would be to use what fits best in your project, the time difference will be a few microseconds per request.

Answer (score 0):

So when we use Eloquent and When DB facades:

When we'll work on a simple and small records site with simple CRUD and there records are not fact, then use Eloquent there. When we'll work on a lot's of records, it is better to use DB Query than Eloquent. So, finally it is cleared that - when we'll use Database Query and When we'll use Eloquent Query.
We use frameworks like Laravel to ease our work. When it comes to concept of frameworks, speed and ease of development is more important than performance. So by using ORM’s it provides powerful methods to handle with database without no need of heavy mysql knowledge. In case of query builder it’s provide methods to build queries in efficient manner.

As my experience there are some things that we can’t easily do with Eloquent. So then we need to use query builder to build direct queries.

So I think it’s not good to compare Eloquent and query builder.

You can find more details here.

But I can give you some tips to select one method.

If you are more aware of efficiency rather than ease of development, go for query builder.
If you dealing with one entity go for ORM, (Eloquent).
If you dealing with multiple entities it’s better to deal with query builder.
If you are new to mysql or your application is not very complex, definitely choose ORM.
If you need more complex query, I recommend to use query builder.